# Print the value of datepicker and send it to my email

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

Hi I have the same issue. Just want to print out the value that was selected on the calendar and include it to send to my email. It prints out to the page but it does not include to the email.

PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {      
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = "Attendance Form";
  $date = $_POST['date[]'];
  $message = "Bro./Sis. ".$name." "."attendance will be at"." ".print_r(date($date['d,m,Y']));    


  $emailTo = "me@domain.com";
  $mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";
  if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $date, $mailHeaders)) {
    $message ='<div class="alert alert-success d-inline-block" role="alert">Your message has been sent.</div>';
    $type = "success";
  } else {
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger d-inline-block" role="alert">Something went wrong, please try again.</div>';
  }
}

?>
```

Hi guys thank you for your comments. I used the datepicker but whenever I use the jqueryui i cannot pick the value so i put the date as a type. This is my HTML:

```
            <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="attendform" style="top: 50%;transform: translateY(25%) !important;position: relative;">    
                <!--Form for join us-->
                <div class="container bg-light p-5 mt-5 d-inline-block text-center">
                <h2 class="join-title text-center display-4 mb-0">Join us!</h2><br><br>

                  <div class="mt-0 mb-3" id="error"><? echo $error.$message; ?></div>

                      <div class="container text-center">
                        <form class="" method="post">
                          <label for="name" class="text-dark border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" >Name: </label> <br>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Bro./Sis."><br>

                          <label for="email">Email</label>
                          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="user@domain.com" required> <br>
                      <!---->
                            <label for="date" class="d-inline-block">Date: </label>
                            <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date[]" class="form-control" value=""></input><br>


                          <input class="btn btn-dark" id="sendbtn" type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
                          </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I disable the jquery datepicker first and try with the normal calendar

```
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--script-->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {
                   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
          </script> -->
```

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the interface between jQuery and PHP. Can you [edit] your post to include the code that posts the values please.

Comment: Looks like you are addressing $_POST['date[]'] as an HTML array, is the datepicker sending down an array?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure the answer:

PHP code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {      
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = "Attendance Form";
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $member = $_POST['member'];
  $message = "Bro./Sis. ".$name." "."($member)"."\n\n"."Schedule:"." "."($date)";


  $emailTo = "me@domain.com";
  $mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";
  if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $mailHeaders)) {
    $message ='<div class="alert alert-success d-inline-block" role="alert">Your message has been sent.</div>';
    $type = "success";
  } else {
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger d-inline-block" role="alert">Something went wrong, please try again.</div>';
  }
}

?>
```

I edited my form and put the jquery datepicker

```
<form class="" method="post">
  <label for="name" class="text-dark border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" >Name: </label> <br>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Bro./Sis."><br>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="user@domain.com" required> <br>
                      <!---->
  <label for="date" class="d-inline-block">Date: </label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" class="form-control" value=""></input><br>                    

  <p>Are you already a member of the youth?</p>
  <label for=member>
  <input type="radio" name="member" value="Yes member">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="member" value="Non member">No 
  </select><br><br>
  <input class="btn btn-dark" id="sendbtn" type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
```